# R markdown knit error read csv

Tags: r, csv, knitr, r-markdown

I'm new to using R markdownn and don't understand why this chunk works fine but fails when knit?

`{r echo=FALSE}
 
dataframe  <- read_csv("C:\\Users\\me\\downloads\\data\\data.csv")
 
summary(dataframe)`
 
 

 
Quitting from lines 21-30 (test_output.Rmd) 
Error in read_csv("C:\Users\me\downloads\data\data.csv") : 
  could not find function "read_csv"
Calls:  ... handle -> withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval
Execution halted

Is it do with the where knit is looking in terms of its working directory?

- ```{r echo=FALSE} but still outputting to created PDF

Thanks

Comment: looks like you forgot to load the package readr (read_csv is from there)

Comment: Or you can do something like this - if you don't want to load it
dataframe  <- readr:::read_csv("C:\.......

Comment: Thanks, that worked, although despite ```{r echo=FALSE} it is still outputting the R code to the pdf created?

Comment: maybe try {r, echo=FALSE}